# Change hostname from the URL in the Apache Web server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webserver

I have URL for which i need to change the hostname and keep rest of the parameters as it is in the Apache Web Server. For E.g.
**Actual URL** 
/servereq?hname=cs_load_cs&summary=true&contractID=da588be1a59f47cf8f

**To be URL:** /servereq?hname=cs_load_cs&summary=true&contractID=da588be1a59f47cf8f

I tried implementing the change using the Rule:
RewriteRule ^http://actualUrl.corp.com/(.*)$ http://newUrl.corp.com/$1

But the URL is parsed only before the '?' and rest of the doesn't appear in the result. I tested the code at online Tester.
Therefore i looking for a way to achieve this without lost of any parameters.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP_HOST is not part of match in RewriteRule pattern, it is automatically added by the apache.

Try :

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newUrl.corp.com/$1 [NC,L,R,QSA]
```